# from dwr.java to javascript obatain a null object

Tags: javascript, struts, dwr

This is my dwr.xml

```
....
<convert converter="bean" match="it.test.bean.Person"/>
<convert converter="bean" match="it.test.bean.Telephone"/>
....
```

and this is my class Person

```
public class Person implements Serializable{

private int id;
private String name;
private String surname;
....
//with getter and setter method
```

my dwr.java file return an array of object of Person type. When I read the the data in my jsp page with javascript the response.length is 6 like in my dwr.java but of null Object.

I can't figure out where could be the error.
I thank you for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to find the problem is to go trough the check-list as indicated here: http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/support/common_problems.html.

You should activate the debug mode in DWR and check to see if you can get any good object back [from /dwr/ url].

Please consider also add more information to your post if you still face that problem.